# How to get user touch interaction with the application while showing dialog box (popup) in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application which is running all time without going into sleep mode. There is a requirement to reduce display brightness during a time period if a user is not interacting with the application. I know this can be done using `onUserIntercation`, but the issue is, the application has several dialog boxes (popup dialog). When they appear, I cannot get the user interaction. Is there any possible way?

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {

}
```

Comment: Use Service: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy Can you explain more, what are the things need to track on background service?

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy I don't think that just using background service will solve the task.

Comment: You can rework your app to show the views that look like a dialog on top of the main view instead of using dialogs.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yeah, that would be great. I can change all dialogs to Activities and change activity's theme as Dialog. The only issue is the available time. Anyway thanks for the idea.